# How can I select Event log by their InstanceID

Tags: powershell

I would like to get all EventLog entries concerning the system and an error. And among those entries I want to select them by their specific InstanceID.

I am going with a a pipe where I slim down the filter but I don't know how to compare the InstanceID with the value of the InstanceID I want.

```
$sysLog = Get-EventLog -LogName System -EntryType Error |
          Where-Object{$_.InstanceId = 10016}
```

```
+ ... LogName System -EntryType Error | Where-Object{$_.InstanceId = 10016}
+                                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation : (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException
```

Comment: `$_.InstanceId = 10016` -> `$_.InstanceId -eq 10016`. `=` is an assignment operator in PowerShell, not a comparison operator. See [`about_Operators`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-3.0).

Comment: Did you intentionally omit the first line of the error message, something like `"InstanceId" is a write protected property` ?

Comment: along with the "`=` is not `-eq`" notes ... i am curious - why are you NOT using the `-InstanceID` parameter of the cmdlet?

Comment: I did omit the first line because it was written in french and I thought it wouldn't be so interresting on an english speaking plateform.

Comment: I did try to use the -eq but I did encounter error that's why I tried with =. However I dind't think to -instanceID parameter, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

i think that code work :

```
$sysLog = Get-EventLog -LogName System -EntryType Error |  Where-Object{$_.InstanceId -eq 10016}

$sysLog
```

see : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-6

EDIT example with export to log file :

```
Function WriteEventLogFile ([string] $pathToWriteLog, [string] $InstanceId){
    $sysLogItems = Get-EventLog -LogName System -EntryType Error | Where-Object {$_.InstanceId -eq $InstanceId}

    # write-host $sysLogItems

    $sysLogItems | Export-Csv -Path  $pathToWriteLog -NoTypeInformation
}

WriteEventLogFile -pathToWriteLog:"C:\Temp\envent_export.log" -InstanceId:"10016"
```

Comment: Thank you it is working in did the error was on an condition later down the code.

Comment: Hi please share your full powershell code and error .

Comment: Sure It's not much but

Comment: New-Item "C:\Users\BSENELD6\Desktop\test sysLog.txt" -Force

$sysLog = Get-EventLog -LogName System -EntryType Error #| Where-Object{$_.InstanceId = 10016} 

if ($sysLog.InstanceId -eq 10016){
Add-Content -Path "C:\Users\BSENELD6\Desktop\test sysLog.txt" "$sysLog"


}

Comment: `New-Item "C:\Users\BSENELD6\Desktop\test sysLog.txt" -Force`

`$sysLog = Get-EventLog -LogName System -EntryType Error #| Where-Object{$_.InstanceId = 10016}` 

`if ($sysLog.InstanceId -eq 10016){ Add-Content -Path "C:\Users\BSENELD6\Desktop\test sysLog.txt" "$sysLog" }`

Comment: @BrunoSENELLART if i understand want you want you have to export full get-eventlog on a file ?

Comment: well that was the idea, it's for training since I am just begining

Comment: @BrunoSENELLART hi i have edit code to export on csv example file.